# Efficient Way to do Very Complicated SQL Grouping:

Tags: sql

Say you have a table like this:

```
ID | Type | Reference #1 | Reference #2
0  | 1    | [A]          | {a}
1  | 2    | [B]          | {b}
2  | 2    | [B]          | {c}
3  | 1    | [C]          | {d}
4  | 1    | [D]          | {d}
5  | 1    | [E]          | {d}
6  | 1    | [C]          | {e}
```

Is there any good way to group by "Reference #1" and "Reference #2" as a "fallback", for lack of a better way of putting it...

For example, I would like to group the following IDs together:

```
{0} [Unique Reference #1], 
{1,2} [Same Reference #1],
{3,4,5,6} [{3,4,5} have same Reference #2 and {3,6} have same Reference #1]
```

I am at a total loss as to how to do this... Any thoughts?

Comment: are you suggesting the COUNT of reference 1 is something to order by?

Comment: I wouldn't know exactly how to do this but I think you will need to outer-join 2 seperate select statements together to achieve what you want...

Comment: Test Schema: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/86e92

Comment: How would '[Z]', '{e}' be grouped in this example?

Comment: I think this question needs an hierarchical query answer.

Comment: I think ypercube is right. It's not clear from your question how you would group the rows in this SQLFiddle example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0f629 . Is there just 1 group, because rows 0 and 1 are in the same Ref1 group, rows 1 and 2 are in the same Ref2 group, rows 2 and 3 are in the same Ref1 group (but different from the one rows 0 and 1 are in), etc. If you want just one group, you have to incrementally go back and forth between the Ref1 and Ref2 values. This could be done with a recursive query, but you need to have a clear definition of what you mean by grouping here.

Comment: @spinning_plate That would be matched with {3,4,5,6} because they share the same Ref #2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In mellamokb's query, the groupings are dependent on the order of the input.

ie.

```
VALUES
    (0, 1, '[A]', '{a}'),
    (1, 2, '[B]', '{b}'),
    (2, 2, '[B]', '{c}'),
    (3, 1, '[C]', '{d}'), // group 3
    (4, 1, '[D]', '{d}'), // group 3
    (5, 1, '[E]', '{d}'), // group 3
    (6, 1, '[C]', '{e}'); // group 3
```

produces a different result tahn

```
VALUES
    (0, 1, '[A]', '{a}'),
    (1, 2, '[B]', '{b}'),
    (2, 2, '[B]', '{c}'),
    (3, 1, '[C]', '{e}'), //group 3
    (4, 1, '[D]', '{d}'), // group 4
    (5, 1, '[E]', '{d}'), // group 4
    (6, 1, '[C]', '{d}'); // group 3
```

This might be intended, if there is some natural order to the References that you could specify, but its a problem if they are not.  The way to 'solve' this or specify another problem is to say that all equal Reference1s create a set of elements whose members are themselves and those elements whose Reference2 is equal to ***at least one*** member of that set.

In SQL:

```
with groupings as (
  select
    ID,Reference1,Reference2,
    (select min(ID) from Table1 t2
     where t2.Reference1=t1.Reference1 or t2.Reference2=t1.Reference2 ) as minID
  from
    Table1 t1
)
select
    t1.ID,t1.Reference1,t1.Reference2,t1.minid as round1,
    (select min(t2.minid) from
            groupings t2
      INNER JOIN groupings t3 ON t1.Reference2=t2.Reference2
) as minID
  from
    groupings t1
```

This should produce the full grouping each time.

Comment: I have removed my answer since it is partly incorrect, and this is a much better answer.